# draw part of an image with Graphics2D

Tags: java

I have been told that I should only use Graphics2D, but I have run into an issue. I know that with Graphics I can write

```
Graphics.drawImage(
 BufferedImage bi,
 int dx1,
 int xy1,
 int dx2,
 int dy2,
 int sx1,
 int sy1,
 int sx2,
 int xy2,
 ImageObserver observer
)
```

which I need to do because I am using a spritesheet but I am wondering whether I can do something similar with Graphics2D or if I should just forget about Graphics2D and just use Graphics.

Comment: `Graphics2D` is a subclass of `Graphics`. *Anything* that you can do with `Graphics` can be done with `Graphics2D` as well.

Comment: Thanks, that helped alot!